# Pandas convert long to wide based on multi labels(composite keys)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'datatype':['IN','IN','EX','EX','IN','IN','EX','EX'], 'Time': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1], 'filetype': ['img','txt','img','txt','img','txt','img','txt']}, index=['PMSN01001','PMSN01001','PMSN01001','PMSN01001','PMSN01001','PMSN01001','PMSN01001','PMSN01001'])

print(df_input)

id          datatype    Time    filetype
PMSN01001   IN        0       img
PMSN01001   IN        0       txt
PMSN01001   EX        0       img
PMSN01001   EX        0       txt
PMSN01001   IN        1       img
PMSN01001   IN        1       txt
PMSN01001   EX        1       img
PMSN01001   EX        1       txt
```

I want to **reshape the data frame from long to wide format** like the below. I have seen many solutions in the community but few deal with column name setup intuitive and simple enough for beginners like me to understand. **I know I have to use .Pivot somehow but I am struggling with two things: easy way to set up column name and how to set up multiindex(composite primary key)**

worth nothing, for every id, with the combination of ['datatype', 'Time', 'filetype'], can make up to 8 data records(2x2x2). So pivoted columns should also reflect accordingly..i think..

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'datatype_time0':['IN'], 'Time_time0': [0], 'filetype_time0': ['img'],'filetype2_time0':['txt'], 'datatype_time1':['EX'], 'Time_time1':[1],  'filetype_time1': ['img'],'filetype2_time1':['txt']}, index=['PMSN01001'])
df_output
           datatype_time0   Time_time0  filetype_time0  filetype2_time0      datatype_time1 Time_time1  filetype_time1  filetype2_time1
 PMSN01001    IN                 0              img          txt               EX              1                 img              txt
```

I am open to any ways on re-naming the column names as long as i can keep track of what values belongs to what

thanks

Comment: @jezrael, i'm sorry i made a huge mistake. to put it simply, one id can have upto 8 records based on the combination of ['datatype',    'Time',    'filetype']. So the task is to make these in to wide format. I have updated the content, best

Comment: Hmm, so is necessarry remove duplicates first?

Comment: if I understood you correctly. the id itself is duplicate but don't they all make up the minimum unique data record based on the combination of [datatype, Time,  filetype] ?

Comment: So need like `x = df.groupby(['id', 'datatype']).agg(Time=('Time', 'first'), filetype1=('filetype', 'first'), filetype2=('filetype', 'last'))` it means first and last `filetype` per `['id', 'datatype']` ? Are you sure?

Comment: i feel like df.groupby(['id', 'datatype', 'Time','filetype']) makes more sense because im using id + 3 keys as a composite priamry key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `groupby`, `cumcount` and `pivot_table`:

```
x = df.groupby(['id', 'datatype']).agg(Time=('Time', 'first'), filetype1=('filetype', 'first'), filetype2=('filetype', 'last'))
x = x.assign(idx=x.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1).reset_index().pivot_table(index=['id'], columns='idx', 
                    values=['datatype', 'Time', 'filetype1', 'filetype2'], aggfunc='first')
x = x.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
x = x.set_axis([f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in x.columns], axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

```
>>> x
          id  Time_1 datatype_1 filetype1_1 filetype2_1  Time_2 datatype_2 filetype1_2 filetype2_2
0  PMSN01001       1         EX         img         txt       0         IN         img         txt
>>>
```

Comment: thank you, your solution was helpful but can i ask why it's df.groupby(['id', 'datatype']) instead of df.groupby(['id', 'datatype', 'Time', 'filetype'])?

Comment: @WonChulChung It's because those are the columns that make the split :) and you could specify more columns but simply those two are enough to determine the splits. Feel free to mark and upvote this if you think it's helpful :)